# Is there anyway to do the dynamic operations on Select statement in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a select query to take the data for report creation, one column in the report is calculated using a formulae that will be added in the query in php code, the formulae keep changing according to the requirement so it need to be pickup and calculated dynamically.

Example of formulae -  c*4.5 , (5*c)/30

The variable part of the formulae always represented as C. It should be replaced with the column content and need to calculate.

this is only a sample...not the original table it contains about 70 fields.

```
Create table ItemCost(Itid int , cost float64);

insert into ItemCost values('1','44.55');
insert into ItemCost values('2','5.55');
insert into ItemCost values('3','7');
```

I have tried to make the query like below

```
select cast(replace('c * 1.5','c',cost) as float64) from ItemCost.
```

But i didn't get the result.

Can anyone suggest some methods..?

I cannot use functions that will reduce execution speed

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe you should try use ```EXECUTE IMMEDIATE``` statement.

Comment: It cannot be used inside a select query..